# How to Change Locale Lang setting in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: configuration, locale

locale command should be . LANG=en_US.UTF-8.

**My setting are .**

```
locale 
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

**local file config**

```
   cat /etc/default/locale : 
   LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
   LANGUAGE="en_US:en"

   cat /etc/locale.conf
   LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

What I have already done.

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 : 
Generating locales...
en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Please Let me know if you need any  thing.

**I am not sure /etc/default/locale file is default or custom.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add to my home profile.

gedit ~/.profile its look like:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```

Log out + Log in. And all is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere (can't tell where) the `LC_ALL` environment variable is assigned the value `C`. You need to get rid of that assignment.

The page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables mentions a few files that are typically used to set environment variables persistently.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

According to this useful [link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-3.html):

> Each of the LC_* and LANG variables can contain a locale name of the
>   following form:
>
> ```
> language[_territory[.codeset]][@modifier]
> ```
>
> where language is an ISO 639 language code (lower case), territory is
>   an ISO 3166 country code (upper case), codeset denotes a character
>   set, and modifier stands for other particular attributes (for example
>   indicating a particular language dialect, or a nonstandard
>   orthography).

In order to fix this problem that seems a bug try:

```
  sudo localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

it should compiles file for **locale** and C library.

Comment: Considering that the en_US.UTF-8 locale is already generated, I don't see how generating it again would make a difference to the OP's problem.

Comment: Because I read this "But  unlike the  locales  package, compiled locale definitions are not removed when running locale-gen, and locales  are  compiled  again  only  if  locale source files have changed." in [locale-gen manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/locale-gen.8.html). I guess that -c option in localedef command should compiles file in any case. Unfortunately I couldn't test this on my Ubuntu because my locale is right.